# How to insert autoincrementing id from one table into another in one command (using returning)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've attempted the following:

```
INSERT INTO second_table(id, somethingelse)
VALUES(
       (INSERT INTO first_table(post_text) VALUES('a text') RETURNING id),
       'abcd123'
    );
```

I know how to do select with 2 query, but I'm trying to avoid any concurrency issue by doing these 2 insertions at once. Above gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 3:         (INSERT INTO first_table(post_text) VALUES('a text...
```

I'm trying to insert auto-incrementing `id` from `first_table` into `second_table` when a row is inserted into `first_table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with first_insert as (
  INSERT INTO first_table(post_text) 
  VALUES('a text') 
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO second_table(id, somethingelse)
select id, 'abcd123'
from first_insert;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a trigger to be executed whenever a row is inserted in first table.
something like:

CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT OF post_text
ON first_table
[
 INSERT INTO second_table(id, somethingelse)
VALUES(
       (select id from first_table where post_text='a text'),
       'abcd123'
    );
];

Answer (score 0):

You need to run below command to off identity column
    Set Identity_Insert [TableName] Off